# Centos Web Server laravel slow site

Tags: memory, centos, php, mysql, top

I have a problem with memory on my centos server when I reboot the server it is fine, oh and by the way, this server is hosting only one website with Apache web server and MySQL as the database. after a while using the website the ram goes up (i think it is the MySQL which is occupying the ram) though I am not an expert. this is my top

```
top - 04:22:05 up  1:46,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.10, 0.19
Tasks: 110 total,   1 running, 109 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3882024 total,   739856 free,  2927996 used,   214172 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4063228 total,  4063228 free,        0 used.   697676 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5149 mysql     20   0 1379456 215028   8472 S   0.3  5.5   0:02.49 mysqld
    1 root      20   0  125368   3816   2508 S   0.0  0.1   0:07.19 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.05 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.31 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.51 migration/0
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:05.80 rcu_sched
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.07 watchdog/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.22 watchdog/1
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.68 migration/1
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.29 ksoftirqd/1
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H
   17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kdevtmpfs
   18 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 writeback
   21 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
   22 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
   23 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
   24 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md
   31 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kswapd0
   32 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd
   33 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:04.05 khugepaged
   34 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto
   42 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld
   44 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpath_rdacd
   45 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kpsmoused
   47 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ipv6_addrconf
   66 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 deferwq
   99 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.06 kauditd
  283 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mpt_poll_0
  284 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff
  285 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mpt/0
  291 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0
  292 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_0
  293 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1
  294 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.58 kworker/u4:2
  295 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_1
  296 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_2
  297 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_2
  302 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ttm_swap
  375 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush
  376 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
  387 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush
  388 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
  401 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
  402 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfsalloc
  403 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs_mru_cache
  404 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-buf/dm-0
  405 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-data/dm-0
  406 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-conv/dm-0
  407 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-cil/dm-0
  408 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-reclaim/dm-
  409 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-log/dm-0
  410 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-eofblocks/d
  411 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.94 xfsaild/dm-0
  479 root      20   0   36828   4460   4140 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.65 systemd-journal
  500 root      20   0  127044   1344    964 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lvmetad
  508 root      20   0   44012   2024   1304 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.43 systemd-udevd
  588 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-buf/sda1
  589 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-data/sda1
  590 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-conv/sda1
  591 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-cil/sda1
```

could you guys please help me to detect my problem and solve this issue.

Edited:

```
top - 10:33:53 up  6:00,  2 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.04, 0.05
Tasks: 113 total,   1 running, 112 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3882024 total,   574780 free,  2926408 used,   380836 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4063228 total,  4063228 free,        0 used.   684364 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0  190896   3816   2508 S   0.0  0.1   0:03.88 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.23 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.38 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.22 migration/0
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:04.67 rcu_sched
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.19 watchdog/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:04.08 watchdog/1
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 migration/1
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.33 ksoftirqd/1
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H
   17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kdevtmpfs
   18 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 khungtaskd
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 writeback
   21 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
   22 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
   23 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
   24 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md
   31 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kswapd0
   32 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd
   33 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.69 khugepaged
   34 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto
   42 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld
   44 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpath_rdacd
   45 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kpsmoused
   47 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ipv6_addrconf
   66 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 deferwq
   98 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.29 kauditd
  284 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff
  286 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 scsi_eh_0
  288 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_0
  289 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1
  290 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_1
  291 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 mpt_poll_0
  293 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mpt/0
  297 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_2
  298 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_2
  301 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ttm_swap
  373 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush
  374 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
  385 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush
  386 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
  399 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
  400 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfsalloc
  401 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs_mru_cache
  402 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-buf/dm-0
  403 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-data/dm-0
  404 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-conv/dm-0
  405 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-cil/dm-0
  406 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-reclaim/dm-
  407 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-log/dm-0
  408 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-eofblocks/d
  409 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:06.51 xfsaild/dm-0
  478 root      20   0   36828   7620   7292 S   0.0  0.2   0:02.62 systemd-journal
  501 root      20   0  127044   1340    964 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lvmetad
  507 root      20   0   43916   1920   1300 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.13 systemd-udevd
  556 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-buf/sda1
  557 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-data/sda1
  558 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-conv/sda1
  559 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-cil/sda1
  560 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-reclaim/sda
  561 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-log/sda1
  562 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-eofblocks/s
  568 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfsaild/sda1
  605 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.09 kworker/0:1H
  622 root      16  -4   55452   1068    616 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.51 auditd
  644 root      20   0   21620   1288    972 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.11 irqbalance
  645 root      20   0  219240   5508   3804 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.03 abrtd
  648 libstor+  20   0    8532    800    648 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.31 lsmd
  650 root      20   0  127888   2320   1744 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.02 smartd
  651 dbus      20   0   26636   1904   1352 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.84 dbus-daemon
  656 chrony    20   0  100432   1520   1152 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.03 chronyd
  662 root      20   0  277656   7756   6716 S   0.0  0.2   0:02.15 rsyslogd
  663 root      20   0    6472    648    540 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.88 rngd
  665 polkitd   20   0  536988  12932   4944 S   0.0  0.3   0:00.39 polkitd
  666 root      20   0   24204   1680   1380 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.47 systemd-logind
  667 root      20   0  216912   4720   3316 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.06 abrt-watch-log
  687 root      20   0  126236   1580    952 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.16 crond
  691 root      20   0   25856    936    732 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 atd
  703 root      20   0  333932  28696   6700 S   0.0  0.7   0:01.65 firewalld
  704 root      20   0  553636   8936   6628 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.89 NetworkManager
  806 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:1H
 1028 root      20   0  105996   4128   3144 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.75 sshd
 1029 root      20   0  562416  16580   5872 S   0.0  0.4   0:10.64 tuned
 1032 root      20   0  614888  38264  29376 S   0.0  1.0   0:04.33 httpd
 1044 root      20   0  110044    828    700 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 agetty
 1236 apache    20   0  620288  27268  15228 S   0.0  0.7   0:01.06 httpd
 1237 apache    20   0  620188  24352  12412 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.38 httpd
 1238 apache    20   0  620244  24824  12788 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.38 httpd
 1239 apache    20   0  620244  23472  11452 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.41 httpd
 1240 apache    20   0  620244  23464  11448 S   0.0  0.6   0:01.15 httpd
 1336 apache    20   0  620240  25172  13160 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.33 httpd
 1338 apache    20   0  620244  25068  13048 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.39 httpd
 2019 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.43 kworker/u4:0
 2686 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u4:2
 2922 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:2
 2973 apache    20   0  618132  21028  11144 S   0.0  0.5   0:00.23 httpd
 2976 apache    20   0  618136  20972  11092 S   0.0  0.5   0:00.06 httpd
 2977 apache    20   0  618136  18972   9140 S   0.0  0.5   0:00.09 httpd
 3208 root      20   0  150376   5948   4628 S   0.0  0.2   0:03.40 sshd
 3212 root      20   0  116452   3176   1684 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.22 bash
 3344 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.23 kworker/0:1
 3361 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kworker/0:2
 3414 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kworker/1:1
 3519 mysql     20   0 1248652 203864   6340 S   0.0  5.3   0:00.75 mysqld
 3549 root      20   0  122856   2612   1484 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.09 htop
 3550 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.08 kworker/0:0
 3562 root      20   0  150376   5960   4640 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.20 sshd
 3569 root      20   0  116584   3348   1776 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 bash
 3624 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:3
 3656 root      20   0  157584   2052   1484 R   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
```

**Edited**

this is my new log today

```
top - 01:23:05 up 1 day, 20:50,  1 user,  load average: 0.02, 0.03, 0.05
Tasks: 110 total,   1 running, 109 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3882024 total,   409032 free,  2965268 used,   507724 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4063228 total,  4063228 free,        0 used.   606968 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 9828 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.02 kworker/0:1
 9840 root      20   0  157588   2104   1508 R   0.3  0.1   0:00.01 top
    1 root      20   0  190896   3816   2508 S   0.0  0.1   0:15.35 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.72 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.06 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+
    7 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.30 migration/0
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:15.85 rcu_sched
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:08.86 watchdog/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:05.64 watchdog/1
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.16 migration/1
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.98 ksoftirqd/1
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:+
   17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kdevtmpfs
   18 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.18 khungtaskd
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.75 writeback
   21 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
   22 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
   23 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
   24 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md
   31 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kswapd0
   32 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd
   33 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.86 khugepaged
   34 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto
   42 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld
   44 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpath_rda+
   45 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kpsmoused
   47 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ipv6_addrc+
   66 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 deferwq
   98 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.86 kauditd
  284 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff
  286 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 scsi_eh_0
  288 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_0
  289 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1
  290 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_1
  291 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.09 mpt_poll_0
  293 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mpt/0
  297 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_2
  298 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_2
  301 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ttm_swap
  373 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush
  374 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
  385 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush
  386 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
  399 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
  400 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfsalloc
  401 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs_mru_ca+
  402 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-buf/dm+
  403 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-data/d+
  404 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-conv/d+
  405 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-cil/dm+
  406 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-reclai+
  407 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-log/dm+
  408 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-eofblo+
  409 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:26.93 xfsaild/dm+
  478 root      20   0   36832   5824   5496 S   0.0  0.2   0:11.50 systemd-jo+
  501 root      20   0  127044   1340    964 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lvmetad
  507 root      20   0   43916   1920   1300 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.13 systemd-ud+
  556 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-buf/sd+
  557 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-data/s+
  558 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-conv/s+
  559 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-cil/sd+
  560 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-reclai+
  561 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-log/sd+
  562 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs-eofblo+
  568 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfsaild/sd+
  605 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.66 kworker/0:+
  622 root      16  -4   55452   1072    620 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.29 auditd
  644 root      20   0   21620   1288    972 S   0.0  0.0   0:25.47 irqbalance
  645 root      20   0  219240   5508   3804 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.03 abrtd
  648 libstor+  20   0    8532    800    648 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.80 lsmd
  650 root      20   0  127888   2320   1744 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 smartd
  651 dbus      20   0   26636   1904   1352 S   0.0  0.0   0:05.92 dbus-daemon
  656 chrony    20   0  100432   1520   1152 S   0.0  0.0   0:10.60 chronyd
  662 root      20   0  299008   6344   5192 S   0.0  0.2   0:13.35 rsyslogd
  663 root      20   0    6472    648    540 S   0.0  0.0   0:06.73 rngd
  665 polkitd   20   0  536988  12932   4944 S   0.0  0.3   0:01.22 polkitd
  666 root      20   0   24204   1680   1380 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.36 systemd-lo+
  667 root      20   0  216912   4720   3316 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.19 abrt-watch+
  687 root      20   0  126236   1580    952 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.66 crond
  691 root      20   0   25856    936    732 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 atd
  703 root      20   0  333932  28696   6700 S   0.0  0.7   0:02.66 firewalld
  704 root      20   0  553636   8936   6628 S   0.0  0.2   0:10.06 NetworkMan+
  806 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kworker/1:+
 1028 root      20   0  105996   4128   3144 S   0.0  0.1   0:04.21 sshd
 1029 root      20   0  562416  16580   5872 S   0.0  0.4   0:33.34 tuned
 1032 root      20   0  614888  38264  29376 S   0.0  1.0   0:14.97 httpd
 1044 root      20   0  110044    828    700 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 agetty
 1237 apache    20   0  704084  35196  19972 S   0.0  0.9   0:13.16 httpd
 3519 mysql     20   0 1581076 215484   8156 S   0.0  5.6   2:10.94 mysqld
 5779 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.24 kworker/u4+
 6168 rpc       20   0   64956   1372    816 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.35 rpcbind
 7116 apache    20   0  704892  35116  19132 S   0.0  0.9   0:02.59 httpd
 7239 apache    20   0  704164  32272  17072 S   0.0  0.8   0:03.95 httpd
 7244 apache    20   0  621704  29504  16052 S   0.0  0.8   0:03.00 httpd
 7251 apache    20   0  703988  33488  18408 S   0.0  0.9   0:01.32 httpd
 7339 apache    20   0  704056  30304  15248 S   0.0  0.8   0:07.78 httpd
 7379 apache    20   0  620236  24764  12700 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.80 httpd
 7380 apache    20   0  620252  24564  12512 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.81 httpd
 7390 apache    20   0  620192  23236  11288 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.77 httpd
 9260 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 kworker/u4+
 9704 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kworker/1:1
 9722 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:2
 9743 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.37 kworker/0:0
 9764 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:2
 9765 apache    20   0  617104  12044   3088 S   0.0  0.3   0:00.15 httpd
 9775 root      20   0  147800   5472   4196 S   0.0  0.1   0:02.26 sshd
 9777 root      20   0  116584   3344   1772 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.17 bash
```

you know my problem is when I reboot the server everything is fine and my site will load smoothly and fast but after a while, it starts to get kinda slow and it loads the pictures so so slow. and my website is php laravel. what else you think should I log and send.

Comment: You need to check that this is actually a problem - it might simply be heading towards a steady state. To monitor processes over some time, there are some useful ideas at [How to monitor and log the memory/cpu usage of processes over time?](https://serverfault.com/q/163563/109573)

Comment: That `top` does not show 94% of the RAM usage. There are only 63 of 109 processes displayed. You may want to check on how to put a program's output into a file.

Comment: @TurboJ I sent the full process

Comment: What is the problem? The amount of memory used by mysqld has gone down between the first and second examples.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have enabled swap memory